# loading textures in C++ OpenGL using DevIL

Tags: c++, opengl, devil

Using C++, I'm trying to load a texture into OpenGL using DevIL. After scrounging around for different code segments, I have a bit of code done (shown below), but it doesn't seem to work completely.

Loading a texture (Part of a Texture2D class):

```
void Texture2D::LoadTexture(const char *file_name) 
{   
    unsigned int image_ID;

    ilInit();
    iluInit();
    ilutInit();

    ilutRenderer(ILUT_OPENGL);

    image_ID = ilutGLLoadImage((char*)file_name);

    sheet.texture_ID = image_ID;
    sheet.width = ilGetInteger(IL_IMAGE_WIDTH);
    sheet.height = ilGetInteger(IL_IMAGE_HEIGHT);
}
```

This compiles and works fine. I do realise that I should only do the ilInit(), iluInit(), and ilutInit() once, but if I remove those lines the program instantly breaks upon loading any image (compiles fine, but errors on runtime).

Displaying the texture in OpenGL (Part of the same class):

```
void Texture2D::Draw() 
{

    glEnable(GL_BLEND);
    glBlendFunc(GL_SRC_ALPHA,GL_ONE_MINUS_SRC_ALPHA);
    glPushMatrix();

    u = v = 0;

    // this is the origin point (the position of the button)
    VectorXYZ point_TL; // Top Left 

    VectorXYZ point_BL; // Bottom Left
    VectorXYZ point_BR; // Bottom Right
    VectorXYZ point_TR; // Top Right

    /* For the sake of simplicity, I've removed the code calculating the 4 points of the Quad. Assume that they are found correctly. */

    glColor3f(1,1,1);
    // bind the appropriate texture frame
    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, sheet.texture_ID);

    // draw the image as a quad the size of the first loaded image
        glEnable(GL_TEXTURE_2D);
        glBegin(GL_QUADS);
            glTexCoord2f (0, 0);
            glVertex3f  (point_TL.x, point_TL.y, point_TL.z); // Top Left

            glTexCoord2f (0, 1);
            glVertex3f  (point_BL.x, point_BL.y, point_BL.z); // Bottom Left

            glTexCoord2f (1, 1); 
            glVertex3f  (point_BR.x, point_BR.y, point_BR.z); // Bottom Right

            glTexCoord2f (1, 0);
            glVertex3f  (point_TR.x, point_TR.y, point_TR.z); // Top Right
        glEnd();
        glPopMatrix();
    glDisable(GL_BLEND);
    glDisable(GL_TEXTURE_2D);
}
```

Currently, the quad shows up, but its completely white (the background colour it's given). The image I'm loading exists and is loaded fine (verified using the loaded size values).

Another few things I should note:
1) I am using a depth buffer. I've heard this doesn't go well with GL_BLEND?
2) I would really like to use the ilutGLLoadImage function.
3) I appreciate example code, as I'm a newbie to openGL and DevIL as a whole.

Comment: Are you sure, that there is a valid OpenGL context at the time of loading the texture?

Comment: What does a [`glGetError()`](http://www.opengl.org/sdk/docs/man/xhtml/glGetError.xml) after your `ilutGLLoadImage()` call return?

Comment: @ datenwolf: I'm pretty sure, but not completely. If you could direct me as to how to ensure there is a valid OpenGL context, I'd be happy to check.

Comment: @genpfault: I wasn't sure how to obtain the output from glGetError(), so I used an if statement checking if glGetError() == GL_NO_ERROR. It -doesn't- enter the if, on either side of the ilutGLLoadImage() statement.

Comment: So you're getting some kind of error before `ilutGLLoadImage()`.  Which one?  I'm betting `GL_INVALID_OPERATION`.

Comment: @genpfault: I'm not sure how to check. I'm running a Win32 application, so my console is disabled (no cout). What's the return type of glGetError() ? I could try using a modified break point...

Comment: OpenGL returns integer error code, but the constants are in the header file - you can compare them easily. Also fopen() the log file, if you do not have the console.

Comment: @genpfault: You're right, it's a GL_INVALID_OPERATION error. Unfortunately I can think of too many reasons why it would occur :/. I'm not at all familiar with OpenGL. Anything I can do to fix it?

Comment: @Viktor Latypov: thanks for the tip. I'll use it when I get around to editing the necessary code (My program is a lot larger than those two functions)

Comment: Tell us the video card and drivers - OpenGL can fail on some filtering modes for textures.

Comment: @Rohit: Check my addition to the answer - it may be just a non-rectangular image (you didn't tell us that)

Comment: @Viktor Latypov: My image is not power-of-2 based, but I thought DevIL manages anyway?

Also, I have an Nvidia NVS 4200M with a driver version 8.17.12.7533, if that helps...

Comment: Your videocard is perfectly suitable. The only reason left is datenwolf's remark on the validity of OpenGL context and multithreading issues. Do you call wglMakeCurrent() before loading image ?

Comment: @Viktor Latypov: Yup, I do. I should note here, that I can display coloured polygons like quads and triangles easily. It's just the texture that isn't showing up.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you have the problem. There might be issues with ilutGLLoadImage().

Try doing things manually:

1. Load the image using ilLoadImage
2. Generate the OpenGL texture handle using the glGenTextures
3. Upload the image to OpenGL glTextImage2D and ilGetData()

See this link for a working solution

http://r3dux.org/tag/ilutglloadimage/

I know, this solution seems to be "a little" complicated, but nobody knows jow much time you would spend fighting with this bug hidden deep in the DevIL.

Another way of fixing things: check you GL texture setup code. Anything in the filtering can be a reason for GL_INVALID_OPERATION.

We've a lot of times into the "White texture" issue while programming the old ATI cards.

Oh!  The biggest guess: Non-power-of-two textures. Is you texture file 2^N by 2^N or something different ?

To use non-rectangular textures you just have to use GL extensions.

And the other one: are you using the textures in the same thread or in the other ? Remember that you should glGenTextures() and glBindTexture()/glBegin/glEnd in the same thread.

Comment: Alright. Edited my function to do it in the same way the tutorial (link) did it. I seem to be getting an access violation error at the -exact- line ilLoadImage() (See line 22 in the paste provided). I'm stumped :/.

Due to the code being long-ish, I put it on paste-bin: http://pastebin.com/TK4yGwHc

Comment: Well, check the error code for the ilBindImage and ilGenImages call

Comment: I ran ilGetError() calls before and after both statements; they both return IL_NO_ERROR.